# Check file with extension .ocx is in use or not using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to check if the excel.exe, mscomct2.ocx or MSCOMCTL.ocx is in use or not using vbscript. I tried to query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE '%" & filename & "%'" but it doesn't work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the OS the list of applications using a module

```
tasklist /m mscomct2.ocx
```

Something like

```
    If moduleInUse( "mscomct2.ocx" ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "Module is in use"
    End If 


Function moduleInUse( moduleName )
    moduleInUse = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run( _ 
        "cmd /c tasklist /m " + moduleName + " | find /i """+ moduleName +"""", 0,True _ 
    ) = 0
End Function
```